# Cassandra mathematical operations within a single row

Tags: cassandra, cql

Suppose there is a table holding some points with columns id (primary key), and coordinates x, y, z

Suppose I wanted to add an extra column calculating say average value of x, y and z for every point. Is that possible through cqlsh? Or would I have to select all the rows, modify them, and write them back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To physically write them as a new column, you'd need to query them, do the average, and then write it back explicitly.

However, you could also calculate the average on the fly - if you want to do that, the concepts you're looking for are:

[User Defined Functions](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCreateUDF.html) or [User Defined Aggregates](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCreateUDA.html)